# Core Data error code=134030 "An error occurred while saving" with no userInfo

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app built in Swift 3 using Xcode 8 GM seed. The app has a keyboard extension. I'm using the shared group directory for the sqlite db location, and database access is done using a framework. Things are working until I try to call SaveContext() from the keyboard. I get the error mentioned in the title error code=134030. The message says "An error occurred while saving" and there is no additional information. There's no userInfo for me to get at the underlying error.

I've dumped out some debug information to make sure I'm looking at the same instance of the same item that I'm trying to update. It's a very simple update, just incrementing a use counter when something is used. Is there some problem with saving from a keyboard extension? Do they open in read-only mode?

Here's the bulk of the CoreDataStack:

```
let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack()

public class CoreDataStack {

public func saveContext()
{
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let error {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Private

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
}()

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let modelUrl = Bundle(identifier: "com.myapp.AppDataKit")?.url(forResource: "MyApp-SE", withExtension: "momd")
    let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelUrl!)!
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp-SE", managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: try! FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.myapp")!.appendingPathComponent("MyAppSEData.sqlite"))]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

} // class CoreDataStack
```

In the catch I'm examining error and I can't get any more info from it. After casting it to NSError it still doesn't help since userInfo is an empty dict.
I haven't implemented the error handling as yet, but I can see the items in the keyboard so there's no issues with the retrieval. Only when saving does it crash.
The place where I'm attempting the update is ridiculously simple:

```
item.useCount = NSNumber(value: item.useCount.intValue + 1)
Logger.add(item.debugDescription)
AppData.SaveContext()
```

AppData is a class with static functions to access core data

```
public class AppData {
    public static func SaveContext() {
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
    }
    ...
}
```

I looked at the device log and didn't get any better information there. I can see the two lines in my data kit and then two from libswiftCore.dylib

```
0   libswiftCore.dylib  0x0000000100ab2848 0x100a80000 + 206920
1   libswiftCore.dylib  0x0000000100ab2848 0x100a80000 + 206920
```

Anyone know how to symbolicate libswiftcore in Xcode8?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out that it was because the "Allow Full Access" option for the keyboard was turned off. So if you want to be able to write to the shared group folder, including updating a sqlite db, you have to install the app & keyboard and check the "Allow Full Access" option first. Then you can return to Xcode and run the extension in debug mode. The setting is retained and everything should work.

Mike